# Can't write results in the concerning columns using the below approach

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, range

I've written a script in vba to scrape some names populated upon initiating searches from a webpage. My below script takes input from `coulmn A` in `Sheet2` and write the result in `column B` right next to concerning rows. 
The script write the results flawlessly if I try like this:

`Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(R + 1, 2) = post.innerText`

or

`cel(1, 2) = post.innerText`

But it throws an error (`object doesn't support this property or method`) when i try like this:

`Sheets("Sheet2").cel(1, 2) = post.innerText`

This is the script:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FetchInfo()
    Const URL As String = "https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q="
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, cel As Range, R&

    For Each cel In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
        With Http
            .Open "GET", URL & cel, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        Set post = Html.querySelector("#results li.type-company h3 a")
        If Not post Is Nothing Then
            R = R + 1: Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(R + 1, 2) = post.innerText  'working one
            cel(1, 2) = post.innerText  'working one
'            Sheets("Sheet2").cel(1, 2) = post.innerText 'doesn't work
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

To get the results in `column B`, place the inputs in `column A` from `Range("A2")` to whatever.

Serch inputs:

```
Nike Care
Nike Cloud
Nike Construction
Nike Foundation
Nike Homes
```

***My question is how can I make this line fully qualified `Sheets("Sheet2").cel(1, 2) = post.innerText`***

Fyi, I'm only seeking any solution the way I tried and failed.

Comment: `cel` is just a placeholder. It can be any names.

Comment: Oh I see you are using it to iterate but it is not a method or property of Worksheet object so can't be used in that way.

Comment: Okay, lets say I wanna initiate search from `sheet2` and get the results in `sheet3`. What would be the approach using `cel(1, 2) = post.innerText`?

Comment: Item is the default property of the range object which is what I think you are accessing with your working version. cel.item(1, 2). It is not a property for use with Worksheet object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Item` is the default property of the `Range` object which is what I think you are accessing with your working version i.e.`cel.item(1, 2)`. It is not a property for use with `Worksheet` object and `cel`, as a variable, will not be recognised as an access method for Worksheet.

You can wrap it in a recognised Range member:

```
Range(cel(1, 2).Address)
```

Fully qualifying in a long winded way might be as follows (please let someone have a shorter method):

```
Debug.Print Worksheets(cel.Parent.NAME).Range(cel(1, 2).Address).Address(external:=True)
```

As per your implementation:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(cel(1, 2).Address) = post.innerText
```

Comment: It seems to be working `Range(cel(1, 2).Address) = post.innerText`. You are very close.

Comment: Is it possible now to give a further twitch by defining method or property to ithis range. What a shallow knowledge i've in vba!!!!